# How to apply rest architecture best practice in controller layer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, routes

I have 2 controllers:

1. Product
2. Review

I'm creating a REST API and I'm thinking that rest architecture will be like

```
  1  GET :  api/products/5
  2  GET :  api/products/5/reviews
  3  GET :  api/products/5/reviews/3
```

But I can get all reviews without product Id or I can get just one review

```
  4  GET :  api/reviews
  5  GET :  api/reviews/3
```

What is the difference between #3 and #5? Two of them return the same values. I need to write 2 of them in controllers (review, products).

What is the best practice for this?

Comment: In one case you have two ids (3), for the other (5) you have one. Supposing that 3 is a unique id for reviews, you could re-route 3 to 5 through a HTTP 301 (moved).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, if the argument to reviews is the id of the specific review, it looks like the route `api/products/5/reviews/3` would return the single review:3 only if it is associated with that product:5 and otherwise return 404, while the route `api/reviews/3` would always return the single review without filtering on product.

I think any answer here will be subjective, but it is important to keep your interface simple, and not do the same thing in two different places.

This is probably how I would do it:

`/api/products/{id}` returns products

`/api/reviews/{id}` return individual reviews

`/api/products/{id}/reviews` could return all the reviews for that product.

I would not implement: `/api/products/{id}/reviews/{reviewid}`